# Export an object form another file didnt work - JS

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am using in functions as a object in JavaScript.
I look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) of import object and 
I tried to make the class in map.js and i want this class in main.js.

## main.js

```
import {Map} from 'map';
var myMap = new Map();
```

## map.js

```
export function Map  () {
    this.a;
    this.b

    this.sum() = function(){
    }
....    
};
```

as i see everything is good in my code. why i still didn't work?
there is any connection to the webStorm ? 
I don't want to use Node.js just Js.

Comment: Where does `MapController` come from?

Comment: Define "didn't work". Good questions have clear problem statements. Examine log files and console output. **Quote error messages**.

Comment: How are you running that code? Many browsers don't support `import` and other things yet.

Comment: "I don't want to use Node.js just Js" — This is akin to saying "I don't want to use a book, just English". Node.js is a tool for executing programs written in the JavaScript programming language. If you don't use *some* tool, then you are reduced to running through experiments in your head to figure out what code will do.

Comment: Sorry about the mass, i steel need to get use to write explaining question.
what i mean is:
i had an object in other file with a lot of functionally.
i would like to do him as a component - import him from another file and then use this component in html file.
i run this on chrome browser. so it's not the problem.
this component need to be pure client js .
i don't need any use with node.
how can i import an object correctly to another js file? @Quentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) this is a programm that can import modules based on ES6 syntax. You need this because almost no browser currently supports Javascript modules so you need a third-party tool to do that for the browser.

You can also use a bundler like [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) which bundles all required files into a single Javascript file.

Take a look at these tools and try first to solve it by yourself. If you run into trouble we're glad to help.

Comment: thank you very much, you touch in the point that i was need.
But i can't use any other library. i need that it will work exactly like any other running of web developing without any external tools.
There is any way to write a component that consist bunch of functions that I can use it in another js file?

Comment: Hmmm. As far as I know there isn't a way arround this. Why don't you want to use any tools? When you bundle them with webpack or babel (as joey said) you get just one Javascript file which you then deploy. The end users then only load one Javascript file. If you don't want to bundle them you have to use SystemJS (or similar tools).

Answer (score 1):

require() is a NodeJS thing, and import is [es6](http://es6-features.org/) syntax for it.

Just using es6 is not supported by most browsers. You need a compiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to use it.

Comment: if i don't want o use  `reqiure()` of Node.js.
what is the correct way to get an object from another file?

Comment: I always used nodejs or jquery for it, but I guess Wernerson already resolved your problem.

Comment: Wernerson bring me to understand that i cant do it in the way i tried to.
i am looking for a way to write a component that i can use i in another files
without any use in external programs.

Comment: This has also always been a challenge for me. You could do it with HTML but not only JS. Check the link he sent, you will be able to use this type of code: 

    <script src="systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>  
    <script>
      SystemJS.import('/js/main.js');
    </script>